# Caching google map v2 markers bitmaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bitmap

It's going to be a bit long but appreciate if you'll bear with me and im sure this will be usefull for other people as well.

I'm using google map in my android app to place different markers. Each marker belongs to a category which is represented by a bitmap. I've been using the **BitmapFun** sample from [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) to cache bitmaps in my app and im trying to implement the same solution with my google map markers.

My code, which was added to the sample's ImageWorker.java, looks as follows (BitmapWorkerTask already existed and was updated to handle also markers) :

```
private static Map<Marker, BitmapWorkerTask> markerToTaskMap = new HashMap<Marker, BitmapWorkerTask>();

public void loadImage(Object data, Marker marker) {
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }

    BitmapDrawable value = null;

    if (mImageCache != null) {
        value = mImageCache.getBitmapFromMemCache(String.valueOf(data));
    }

    if (value != null) {
        // Bitmap found in memory cache
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(value.getBitmap()));
    } else if (cancelPotentialWork(data, marker)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(marker);
        markerToTaskMap.put(marker, task);

        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.DUAL_THREAD_EXECUTOR, data);
    }
}

private class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, BitmapDrawable> {
    private Object data;
    private WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference = null;
    private WeakReference<Marker> markerReference = null;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    public BitmapWorkerTask(Marker marker) {
        markerReference = new WeakReference<Marker>(marker);
    }

    /**
     * Background processing.
     */
    @Override
    protected BitmapDrawable doInBackground(Object... params) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground - starting work");
        }

        data = params[0];
        final String dataString = String.valueOf(data);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        BitmapDrawable drawable = null;

        // Wait here if work is paused and the task is not cancelled
        synchronized (mPauseWorkLock) {
            while (mPauseWork && !isCancelled()) {
                try {
                    mPauseWorkLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        // If the image cache is available and this task has not been cancelled by another
        // thread and the ImageView that was originally bound to this task is still bound back
        // to this task and our "exit early" flag is not set then try and fetch the bitmap from
        // the cache
        if (mImageCache != null && !isCancelled() && (getAttachedImageView() != null || getAttachedMarker() != null)
                && !mExitTasksEarly) {
            bitmap = mImageCache.getBitmapFromDiskCache(dataString);
        }

        // If the bitmap was not found in the cache and this task has not been cancelled by
        // another thread and the ImageView that was originally bound to this task is still
        // bound back to this task and our "exit early" flag is not set, then call the main
        // process method (as implemented by a subclass)
        if (bitmap == null && !isCancelled() && (getAttachedImageView() != null || getAttachedMarker() != null)
                && !mExitTasksEarly) {
            bitmap = processBitmap(params[0]);
        }

        // If the bitmap was processed and the image cache is available, then add the processed
        // bitmap to the cache for future use. Note we don't check if the task was cancelled
        // here, if it was, and the thread is still running, we may as well add the processed
        // bitmap to our cache as it might be used again in the future
        if (bitmap != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                // Running on Honeycomb or newer, so wrap in a standard BitmapDrawable
                drawable = new BitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap);
            } else {
                // Running on Gingerbread or older, so wrap in a RecyclingBitmapDrawable
                // which will recycle automagically
                drawable = new RecyclingBitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap);
            }

            if (mImageCache != null) {
                mImageCache.addBitmapToCache(dataString, drawable);
            }
        }

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground - finished work");
        }

        return drawable;
    }

    /**
     * Once the image is processed, associates it to the imageView
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(BitmapDrawable value) {
        // if cancel was called on this task or the "exit early" flag is set then we're done
        if (isCancelled() || mExitTasksEarly) {
            value = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = getAttachedImageView();
            if (value != null && imageView != null) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute - setting bitmap");
                }
                setImageDrawable(imageView, value);
            }
        } else if (markerReference != null) {
            final Marker marker = getAttachedMarker();
            if (value != null && marker != null) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute - setting marker bitmap");
                }
                markerToTaskMap.remove(marker);
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(value.getBitmap()));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(BitmapDrawable value) {
        super.onCancelled(value);
        synchronized (mPauseWorkLock) {
            mPauseWorkLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ImageView associated with this task as long as the ImageView's task still
     * points to this task as well. Returns null otherwise.
     */
    private ImageView getAttachedImageView() {
        if (imageViewReference == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

        if (this == bitmapWorkerTask) {
            return imageView;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Marker getAttachedMarker() {
        if (markerReference == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final Marker marker = markerReference.get();
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = markerToTaskMap.get(marker); //getBitmapWorkerTask(marker);

        if (this == bitmapWorkerTask) {
            return marker;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(Object data, Marker marker) {
    final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = markerToTaskMap.get(marker);

    if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
        final Object bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
        if (bitmapData == null || !bitmapData.equals(data)) {
            bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancelPotentialWork - cancelled work for " + data);
            }
        } else {
            // The same work is already in progress.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you're familiar with the BitmapFun sample you can see that everything is practically the same as using a bitmap with an ImageView, except the use of AsyncDrawable to connect the bitmap to its loading AsyncTask. Since i cant extend the Marker class (it's final) and there's no getIcon() method, i have to maintain a hashmap (markerToTaskMap) to do this job.

This solution seems to work in general, except for a few glitches where im getting a wrong bitmap for a marker. I have no idea why. This doesn't happen with the OOB sample code.

Appreciate if someone could help me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can help you by asking to not do this.

If you want to optimize, know your enemy better. Every call to Google Maps Android API v2 is reaching to other process. And most of them need to be done on main thread.

Because every call to the API is reaching other process synchronously, it will block user interface. E.g. adding 2000 markers on a decent phone will take 1 second (tested). On the other hand loading 20 small bitmaps to represent categories in `onCreate` will take less than 100ms (untested claim). Therefore your code will even slow things down, because you have at least 2 calls to add a `Marker`: `addMarker` and `setIcon`.

Simply load all `Bitmap`s using `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource` into a `Map<Category, BitmapDescriptor>` once and use them as you create `Marker`s.

To sum it up: don't optimize unless there is a problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "know your enemy" a bit more ? Obviously i would prefer your solution for its simplicity but i dont feel im doing here anything exceptionally out of the ordinary. Im still calling Google Map APIs from the UI thread, its just the caching that is being performed asynchronously.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it. Thanks.